# zypper add repository and enable refresh on one line

Tags: linux, repository, zypper

When I add a repository using zypper:

```
zypper ar <url> name
```

then I have to do

```
zypper lr
```

check the number of the repository and enable autorefresh:

```
zypper mr -r 2
```

Can't I do all this in one line?

Comment: You can execute `zypper ar <url> name && zypper lr && zypper mr -r 2`. With `&&`, none of the commands will be executed if the previous did not execute properly.

Comment: yes but the number of the repository is not fixed (not always 2)

Comment: But what do you exactly want? To create an alias or function for that? If so, you can define it so that it accepts some parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after looking around on the internet for a while I found the -f option:

```
zypper ar -f <url> name
```

this enables autorefresh automatically. I am wondering why autorefresh is off by default!

Comment: You don't need to wonder. Just consider a case when the user might need to add several repos, then will need to refresh. This will save some time in case the repos metadata is really large. So just for flexibility its worth to keep auto-refresh off.